Analysis of oscillator circuit
I have encountered the following circuit, and wanted to analyze it's behavior:

The inverters are supplied with Vcc and GND.
I think it's supposed to be a decaying ring oscillator, but have no idea how to approach analyzing such circuit.
Especially considering the properties of the diode and the inverters.
I get that at the initial state (S1 open) the voltages are zero at the lower part of the circuit, the input of U1A is zero and the output of U1C is Vcc.
I also get that the propagation delay of the inverters together with the capacitors cause the oscillations.
But I have no idea how to fully analyze the circuit.

This looks like a variation of a circuit where you give it a smack and it starts at some frequency, then the frequency decreases slowly to zero.  That is called a Wheel Of Fortune circuit, after the main device on a US game show.  In your case, I don't think the frequency decays to zero hertz.
U1A, U1B, and R5 form a non-inverting latch.  Combined with U1C and R4, this forms a Schmitt trigger inverter, like 1/6th of a CD40106.
In the standard oscillator circuit, R3 is the large timing resistor, C2 is the timing capacitor, and all of the rest of the stuff is gone.  This forms a simple squarewave oscillator with a nearly perfect 50/50 duty cycle.
To that, things have been added.
The ratio of R4 to R5 sets the amount of hysteresis.  This affects the peak-to-peak voltage swing across C2.
S1 charges up C1, which injects a DC bias into the input of U1A.  This changes both the frequency and the duty cycle of the oscillator.  C1 is slowly discharged through R1 so the effect decreases over time.
D disconnects R3 from the output during positive half-cycles.  During this period, the only currents available to charge up C2 are some from C3 as it bypasses the reverse-biased diode, and some from C1 through R2.  As C1 discharges over time, this current decreases.  This will cause the overall output frequency to decrease, as the positive half-cycle gets longer and longer.

Let's try to start at the beginning and go step by step. (It will be a bit long.)
The first two inverters and two resistors are a Schmitt trigger. Here you can see the characteristics. The hysteresis can be adjusted (over a relatively wide range) by varying the two resistors.

This becomes an oscillator simply by putting a capacitor at the input, charging it and discharging it with an inverted output. (This could also be the output of the first inverter, then you don't need the third, but we follow the solution of the original schematic.)

So here we have our oscillator, we just need to change the charge and discharge of the capacitor to see the original.

First, let's look at the original situation, i.e. without capacitor C3. When S1 is turned on, we see a fixed frequency oscillator that operates as long as S1 is held down. After S1 is turned off, the frequency decreases and then the oscillation stops (as the voltage at the VC point drops below the upper threshold). Simplified slightly, capacitor C2 is charged by resistor R2 (100 k) and discharged by resistor R3 (10 k) and diode D1. The duty cycle is therefore significantly different from 50%.

The enlarged signal is shown here.

When C3 is added, the charge time of C2 is reduced, thus increasing the frequency of the oscillator. The same could be achieved by reducing the value of resistor R2 or capacitor C2.


